Token swap error 0x26 InvalidSplTokenProgram on raydium rust
i'm currently following this repo https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions/blob/master/client/src/main.rs to perform a raydium swap but when i tried testing, i'm getting error saying 0x26 InvalidSplTokenProgram but i tried checking all the addresses, they seems to be corrected. I'm not sure what did i did wrong to keep getting this error. this is the log i'm getting
user wif account: 4UsPtmr5FYYRpWh8FogkauZxLUXfbx1tfNLEkJfrAxmT
user sol account: 72v4J2YDRZL1Fhgv34wNPhNt2i24hoYusFVxj1MFbLqP
Error: Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x26", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, Custom(38))), logs: Some(["Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [1]", "Program log: Error: InvalidSplTokenProgram", "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 consumed 10066 of 200000 compute units", "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: custom program error: 0x26"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) } 
use crate::constant::SOL_ADDRESS;
use raydium_contract_instructions::amm_instruction::swap_base_in as amm_swap;
use solana_client::nonblocking::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use solana_program::{pubkey, pubkey::Pubkey};
use solana_sdk::{self, signature::Keypair, signer::Signer};
use spl_associated_token_account::get_associated_token_address;
use std::{env, error::Error, str::FromStr, sync::Arc};

pub async fn test_swap() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    /*
    wif-sol pool info from https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json
        {
      id: 'EP2ib6dYdEeqD8MfE2ezHCxX3kP3K2eLKkirfPm5eyMx',
      baseMint: 'EKpQGSJtjMFqKZ9KQanSqYXRcF8fBopzLHYxdM65zcjm',
      quoteMint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      lpMint: 'CQurpF3WS3yEqFEt1Bu8s5zmZqznQG3EJkcYvsyg3sLc',
      baseDecimals: 6,
      quoteDecimals: 9,
      lpDecimals: 6,
      version: 4,
      programId: '675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8',
      authority: '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1',
      openOrders: '6jeayPbLeJq9o6zXbCtLsEJuPyPFyojWoH55xrksfsoL',
      targetOrders: '2yBDs44FDGZeXbnx1MdmAMYx9ndFFVWTbcrjJB1JMLSR',
      baseVault: '7UYZ4vX13mmGiopayLZAduo8aie77yZ3o8FMzTeAX8uJ',
      quoteVault: '7e9ExBAvDvuJP3GE6eKL5aSMi4RfXv3LkQaiNZBPmffR',
      withdrawQueue: '11111111111111111111111111111111',
      lpVault: '11111111111111111111111111111111',
      marketVersion: 4,
      marketProgramId: 'srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX',
      marketId: 'EzMCG3oJpXu2enNAh2A18iSg6Giq3Bt1wPDFDDiYgxeY',
      marketAuthority: 'Bo9ofFBTrT7GjrjZCseQuB7Hd91d9Ya5G3srhUEDBLD2',
      marketBaseVault: '58LQCd9EXd4npbyaPAYztwKr54fHyXkGGUB6zt4GXTLA',
      marketQuoteVault: 'H9uqrbTrpZCVRv2sZah2kf6NfNdV7ZhUJrku1TCfnrsT',
      marketBids: '34bsaKr4CH6YPNJQqXnxp1BGygvqBYKz4RTndbFFrVYe',
      marketAsks: 'C2DK9zXcy2XaMUFDCgtCEkovrYpf1dxB4P1JFEakp9gf',
      marketEventQueue: '6gpR7brnKCPqPwSRCU2PRGGNLEsoqsjudYfMNub5DEYd',
      lookupTableAccount: 'A9F1oBqaAFFJqjmevgeWEDQdhahgkNupsowrWjc5Fwp9'
    }
         */
    // pool info
    let program_id: Pubkey = pubkey!("675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8"); // programId
    let amm_id: Pubkey = pubkey!("EP2ib6dYdEeqD8MfE2ezHCxX3kP3K2eLKkirfPm5eyMx"); // id
    let amm_authority: Pubkey = pubkey!("5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1"); // authority
    let amm_open_orders: Pubkey = pubkey!("6jeayPbLeJq9o6zXbCtLsEJuPyPFyojWoH55xrksfsoL"); // openOrders
    let amm_target_orders: Pubkey = pubkey!("2yBDs44FDGZeXbnx1MdmAMYx9ndFFVWTbcrjJB1JMLSR"); // targetOrders
    let pool_coin_token_account: Pubkey = pubkey!("7UYZ4vX13mmGiopayLZAduo8aie77yZ3o8FMzTeAX8uJ"); // baseVault
    let pool_pc_token_account: Pubkey = pubkey!("7e9ExBAvDvuJP3GE6eKL5aSMi4RfXv3LkQaiNZBPmffR"); // quoteVault
    let serum_program_id: Pubkey = pubkey!("srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX"); // marketProgramId
    let serum_market: Pubkey = pubkey!("EzMCG3oJpXu2enNAh2A18iSg6Giq3Bt1wPDFDDiYgxeY"); // marketId
    let serum_bids: Pubkey = pubkey!("34bsaKr4CH6YPNJQqXnxp1BGygvqBYKz4RTndbFFrVYe"); // marketBids
    let serum_asks: Pubkey = pubkey!("C2DK9zXcy2XaMUFDCgtCEkovrYpf1dxB4P1JFEakp9gf"); // marketAsks
    let serum_event_queue: Pubkey = pubkey!("6gpR7brnKCPqPwSRCU2PRGGNLEsoqsjudYfMNub5DEYd"); // marketEventQueue
    let serum_coin_vault_account: Pubkey = pubkey!("58LQCd9EXd4npbyaPAYztwKr54fHyXkGGUB6zt4GXTLA"); // marketBaseVault
    let serum_pc_vault_account: Pubkey = pubkey!("H9uqrbTrpZCVRv2sZah2kf6NfNdV7ZhUJrku1TCfnrsT"); // marketQuoteVault
    let serum_vault_signer: Pubkey = pubkey!("Bo9ofFBTrT7GjrjZCseQuB7Hd91d9Ya5G3srhUEDBLD2"); // marketAuthority
    let amount_in: u64 = 100000;
    let minimum_amount_out: u64 = 10;

    let url = env::var("RPC_URL").expect("failed getting rpc url");
    let private_key = env::var("PRIVATE_KEY").expect("Failed getting private key");
    let rpc_client = Arc::new(RpcClient::new(url));

    let latest_blockhash = rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().await?;
    let keypair = Keypair::from_base58_string(&private_key);

    let use_wif_account = get_associated_token_address(
        &keypair.pubkey(),
        &Pubkey::from_str("EKpQGSJtjMFqKZ9KQanSqYXRcF8fBopzLHYxdM65zcjm")?, //wif
    );
    println!("user wif account: {:#?}", use_wif_account);
    let user_sol_account =
        get_associated_token_address(&keypair.pubkey(), &Pubkey::from_str(SOL_ADDRESS)?);
    println!("user sol account: {:#?}", user_sol_account);

    let swap_instructions = amm_swap(
        &program_id,
        &amm_id,
        &amm_authority,
        &amm_open_orders,
        &amm_target_orders,
        &pool_coin_token_account,
        &pool_pc_token_account,
        &serum_program_id,
        &serum_market,
        &serum_bids,
        &serum_asks,
        &serum_event_queue,
        &serum_coin_vault_account,
        &serum_pc_vault_account,
        &serum_vault_signer,
        &user_sol_account,
        &use_wif_account,
        &keypair.pubkey(),
        amount_in,
        minimum_amount_out,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let user = keypair.pubkey();

    let tx = solana_sdk::transaction::Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
        &[swap_instructions],
        Some(&user),
        &[&keypair],
        latest_blockhash,
    );

    let signature = rpc_client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&tx).await?;

    println!("swap: {:?}", signature);
    Ok(())
}



hello did you find out what you did wrong ?

I faced a similar issue sometime ago. Issue was that the from and to token accounts i.e. user_sol_account, use_wif_account in your case, were not having token create instructions appended in the transaction instruction.
We need to check and create if associated token account does not exist for the associated token accounts. If wrapped sol account does not exist before hand then a create and transfer instruction needs to be appended for user_sol_account as well
Below method can be used to get create associated account instruction for spl token (other than wrapped sol)
spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
    funding_address: &Pubkey,
    wallet_address: &Pubkey,
    token_mint_address: &Pubkey, //Wif
    token_program_id: &Pubkey //SPL_TOKEN_PROGRAM
) 

For wsol, we can do the following
First create account
solana_program::system_instruction::create_account_with_seed

Then initialize account with token program
spl_token::instruction::initialize_account

If wsol is the base mint, then you can transfer some wsol and then sync account using below instructions before doing the swap
 //Transfer instruction
solana_program::system_instruction::transfer( 
from_pubkey: &Pubkey, //Owners pubkey
to_pubkey: &Pubkey, //Wsol ata
lamports: u64 // Amount
)
//Sync instruction
spl_token::instruction::sync_native(
token_program_id: &Pubkey, 
account_pubkey: &Pubkey //Wsol Ata
)

